# Can I learn acrobatics in a Microlight?

Tags: ultralight

Can I learn acrobatics in a Microlight, such as a C42 or Eurofox?

I would like to extend my abilities beyond getting from A - B but don't want to get a full PPL. I enjoy unusual attitudes too much :)

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to extend my abilities beyond getting from A - B but don't want to get a full PPL

You don't necessarily need a PPL to go do some aerobatics, go and visit someone like the [British aerobatics academy](https://britishaerobaticacademy.com/) at Fowlmere (fly your microlight in - great little airfield too!), and go with one of their fantastic instructors and have some fun.

Without a PPL, you cant add much by way of additional ratings. With a PPL, you can add a Instrument rating - both full and restricted (sometimes called an IMC rating in the UK). You could also add endorsements such as tailwheel, retractable, and variable pitch prop (colloquially: wobbly-prop). All of these things may well improve your skill, and enjoyment of flying beyond the "A-B and back again" that can get a little boring. But does come at a cost!

All that said, here's the answer to your main question.

### C42

The C42 is not approved for aerobatics. It's [type approval](https://www.bmaa.org/files/tads_bm68_ikarus_c42.pdf) under "Permitted Manoeuvres" says:

> Maximum bank angle 60º
> Non Aerobatic
> Normal acceleration limits, +4

## Eurofox

Again, a good place to start is the [type approval sheet](https://www.bmaa.org/files/tads_bm85_eurofox.pdf) and it too is not approved for aerobatics:

> Maximum bank angle 60°
> Non-Aerobatic
> 450kg/472.5kg - Normal acceleration limits, +4g /-2g
> 560kg - Normal acceleration limits, +4g /-1.5g

Comment: Hey Jamie, thanks for the answer... seems that they use a Genevation GenPro, which is under 650kg. So is it a microlight? I want to get to the point where I can do some of the manoeuvres in my own aircraft, so if there are no microlights approved for this, it wouldn't be possible

Comment: Early aerobatics and tuition will most likely use something like a Grob trainer. I would say its hugely unlikely you'd want to do any sort of aerobatics in a microlight. They're just not built for it.